# Not getting output, no errors found ( c language)

Tags: c

C code for calculating simple interest

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float principle, rate, years;
    float simpleInterest = (principle * rate * years)/100;
    printf("Enter the principle");
    scanf("%f", &principle);
    printf("Enter the rate");
    scanf("%f", &rate);
    printf("Enter the years");
    scanf("%f", &years);
    printf("The simple interest is %f", simpleInterest);
}
```

Comment: The program runs from the first line to the last, statement by statement. You use the variables to calculate interest before you actually set them with `scanf`. The result is undefined behavior.

Comment: Hint: what do you think the formula computes *before* you enter the values from which it should derive its answer?

Comment: If you had prior exposure to Excel, formulas in C do *not* have the same behavior of recomputing things as its inputs change; it's a one-time deal - it gets computed at the time the program gets to it.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: In the code shown, using the uninitialized variables results in indeterminate values, not undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil by my knowledge, the act of simply accessing the indeterminate values of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior. And I think [this would seem to support that](https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior#Use_of_an_uninitialized_variable). Unless you meant something else?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: The reference you site is incorrect. Per C 2018 6.7.9 10, “If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate…” Per 3.19.2, an indeterminate value is “either an unspecified value or a trap representation.” Per 3.19.3, an unspecified value is “valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance.” Thus, using an uninitialized object produces either a valid value or a trap representation (but only if the variable type has trap representations).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: There is a rule that can make accessing an uninitialized object have undefined behavior, but it does not apply here. That rule is in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, which says “… If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.” However, as the addresses of these variables are taken, they cannot have been declared `register`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil huh, I see. Looks like you're right :p Thanks for the information, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

C variables are *not* mathematical variables: they do not express a relationship:

```c
int y = x + 1; // this does NOT mean that `y` is always equal to `x + 1`
```

Instead, statements are executed from top to down, and when a variable name comes up in the code, the C language will read its contents[1]. Therefore:

```c
int x = 5;
// now x == 5
int y = x + 1;
// now x == 5 and y == 6
x = 8;
// now x == 8 and y == 6
```

That means that your code should be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) // NOTE: use `int main(void)` instead of `int main()`
{
    float principle, rate, years;

    printf("Enter the principle");
    scanf("%f", &principle);

    printf("Enter the rate");
    scanf("%f", &rate);

    printf("Enter the years");
    scanf("%f", &years);

    float simpleInterest = (principle * rate * years) / 100.0f;

    printf("The simple interest is %f\n", simpleInterest);

    return 0;
}
```

NOTES:

[1] = not always true, because of short circuiting when using operators like `&&` and `||`, and because operators like `sizeof` do not evaluate the expressions. But this is beyond the scope of my answer.